# mock object to return a real object with same arguments

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to mock a factory. In this example, this factory has a method `create` which takes two args and return a C object with has a constructor which takes same two args. I'd like to setup my factory to when I order my factory to create a new C, it returns a real new C with given args to `create` method.

```
Mockito.when(myFactory.create(Mockito.any(A.class), Mockito.any(B.class)))
    .thenReturn(new C(??, ??));
```

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`doAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) to capture and use the parameters passed to the mocked factory call.

For example:

```
MyFactory myFactory = mock(MyFactory.class);

Answer<C> answer = new Answer<C>() {
    public C answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        A a = invocation.getArgument(0, A.class);
        B b = invocation.getArgument(1, B.class);
        return new C(a, b);
    }
};

// either of these ...
when(myFactory.create(Mockito.any(A.class), Mockito.any(B.class))).thenAnswer(answer);

doAnswer(answer).when(myFactory.create(Mockito.any(A.class), Mockito.any(B.class)));
```

Comment: Faster than me, you can also pass the answer as an argument to Mockito.mock(MyFactory.class, answer) and then by testing the value of invocation.getMethod()

Comment: It works! I just had to change `invocation.getArgumentAt(0, A.class);` to `invocation.getArgument(0);` because `InvacationOnMock` didn't have any `getArgumentAt` method, but that's that way to go. Thank you

Comment: @guijob: You can also write it more shortly using lambda - see https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#37 - `Answer<C> answer = (invocation -> new C(invocation.getArgument(0), invocation.getArgument(1)));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyFactory myFactory = mock(MyFactory.class);
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
doReturn(new C(a, b)).when(myFactory).create(eq(a), eq(b));
```

Just import eq method from hamcrest.

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question. He wants the `C()` constructor be called not with new instances of `A` and `B`, but with the same parameters as the `create()` method is called in the time of the test. Look at the glytching's answer to understand your misunderstanding :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek, please, read my code more carefully. It does what you have asked.

Comment: Arguments are configured ahead of invoking and require them to be the same in the invoking of myFactory's create method. Only in this case new C's instance will be returned.

Comment: Your mock returns a new instance of `C` class with **always** the same objects `a`, `b` as were created when you defined the mock. The OP wants that the instance of `C` is created with the concrete values which are passed **after** the creation of the mock, when the test is performed. You do not know them in the time of the mock definition. Please study the glytching's solution and then delete your post - you must refer to the **invocation context** `InvocationOnMock`.

Comment: To make it more concrete: during the test your test class somehow calls `myFactory.create(x, y)`, and the OP wants the method to return `new C(x, y)` - but your mock returns `new C(a, b)` where `a` and `b` are your previously created objects and not `x` and `y`. Well, actually it's even worse - your mock method is not called at all, because of the matchers `eq(a)` and `eq(b)` which you used will not pass on `x` and `y`.

Comment: @HonzaZidek, by the third comment you violated isolation principle. In this context, not MyFactory class is tested. After, describe a case, when factory's logic changes in relation to it's creating method invocations count. If it does, than the problem with the factory.
About previous: InvocationOnMock is pointing to proxy, which is a part of Reflection API, and as it is known, use of Reflection API in tests is the last way to test the object.

Comment: Just try it in a compiler. Your code will not do what you state it does and what the OP requested. That's all.